# Record video but not audio playing on system

Tags: sound, video, webcam

I want to play a video of music, listen on headphones, and record the webcam audio and video as someone sings along. (That will then be mixed with others for a chorus.)

I've used Cheesebox and guvcview but both record the audio from the playing video.

How can I record a video without recording the playing music.

I've seen a lot of question asking the opposite of what I'm trying to do so it seems what I'm attempting is the default situation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several applications and techniques that could be used here but the easiest and probably most effective is to use the application SimpleScreenRecorder, a great front end for FFmpeg:

```
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
```

For this to work in your case you need to:

1. Use the 'Select window...' option for Video Input to select your webcam playback window.
2. Change the Audio Input Source to the source relevant to your webcam.

Here is a screen capture of this working on my own system:

[image]

This worked well on my system and should on yours as well...